# Recovering a unsaved word file after four days

Tags: microsoft-word, data-recovery, file-recovery

I know the unsaved word documents (.asd files) are saved in `C:\Users\"username"\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office\UnsavedFiles` up to four days (tested myself). But  Is there any way to recover an unsaved word document after four days? I am using Microsoft 365 Word. This is the only way to recover my 10 days of work on for a blog and any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Whilst you have my sympathies, this is really just an abbreviated version of yesterday's question. Some form of software disk scavenger is going to be your only hope, same as any other deleted file.  In the meantime have you now set up a proper backup strategy?

Comment: You have cross posted this on the Microsoft Answers Forum and knowledgable people have taken the time to already answer you.

Comment: Many thanks, @Tetsujin I Manged to recover the document using a recovery tool (called recoverit). But instead of my text, all I see is some strange coding for 37 pages (my text is 5-page max). No idea why. 
And yeah, I always save my files in OneDrive, this is one rare occasion where I was completing relying on Blogger. Lesson learned though.

Comment: Thanks @RichMichaels Yeah, I did post it in Microsoft Forum. But I don't see why that should be a problem. They are totally two different resources - not everyone who uses MIcrosoft forum use StackExchange, and vice-versa. I wanted to reach experts in both

Comment: For cross-posting etiquette, please read: http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184